# Automatic replacement of expressions

Tags: linux, regex, find-and-replace

Maybe this can be achieved through (extended) regular expressions, but I really don't know if or how. There seems to be a way to access "things that are found" by using `$1, $2, …` but I have no idea where to use that.

I want to search & replace (in multiple documents) an expression "with holes in it".

Example:

```
<someCodeAndOtherStuffThatAlwaysStaysTheSame
value="somePathThatAlwaysStaysTheSame/horse.mp3">
<moreCodeThatAlwaysStaysTheSame
src="samePathThatAlwaysStaysTheSame/horse.mp3"
<moreCodeThatAlwaysStaysTheSame>
```

should turn into

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

or possibly

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<embed height="50" width="100" src="horse.mp3">
</audio>
```

Of course, `horse.mp3` is variable and the part that I desribed as a "hole".

I mainly use `Bluefish Editor` and `gedit` but a solution using the `terminal`would be just as fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Pattern Capture", where a particular pattern matched by a regular expression is saved in a variable. The details of how this is done depend on the language used (Perl, awk, sed or whatever).

Your problem is a bit more complicated because:

1. You should [not parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1081936)
2. Regular expressions become more complicated in most languages when your search pattern
   spans multiple lines.
3. Since you have not included a sample of your actual code, it is harder for me to find a unique pattern with which to anchor my regular expression. In the script below I am using 
   `<moreCodeThatAlwaysStaysTheSame>` and `.someCodeAndOth` you will need to change that to reflect actual unique patterns that flank the text you want to replace.
4. You should [not parse HTML with regular expressions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

All that said, here is a Perl script that will replace the patterns you gave in your question:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
###############################################
# This sets the line separator to a string    #
# instead of a new line (\n). Use something   #
# that uniquely delimits the code you want to #
# replace.                                    #
###############################################
local $/="<moreCodeThatAlwaysStaysTheSame>";

#######################################################
# Read the input file, line by line. Remember that    #
# because of the previous command, a line is expected #
# to end with "<moreCodeThatAlwaysStaysTheSame>"      #
#######################################################
while (<>) {
#####################################################
# $str is what we want to replace the pattern with. #
# "XXX" will be replaced by the correct mp3.        #
#####################################################
    my $str=<<Eof;
 <audio controls="controls">
   <source src="XXXX" type="audio/mpeg">
<embed height="50" width="100" src="XXXX">
</audio>
Eof
###########################################################
# Match the entire string we will replace AND the         #
# mp3 we are looking for. In Perl (and other languages)   #
# placing a regex pattern in (parentheses) captures it.   #
# We can now refer to the 1st captured pattern as $1, the #
# second as $2 etc.                                       #
###########################################################
    /(.someCodeAndOth.+?src=.+\/(.+?\.mp3).+?$)/s;

###################################################
# Save the matches into variables, otherwise they #
# will be lost at the next match operation.       #
###################################################
    my ($match,$rep,$mp3)=($1,$1,$2);

###################################################
# Replace "XXXX" with the appropriate mp3 in $str #
###################################################
    $str=~s/XXXX/$mp3/g;

#########################################
# Replace the matched pattern with $str #
#########################################
    s/$match/$str/;

#################
# Print it out! #
#################
    print;
}
```

Save that script as `foo.pl` and run it on your file as follows:

```
perl foo.pl input_file.html > output_file.html
```

Comment: This is a great answer with useful example code. I want to stress one thing that has been mentioned by terdon:
_You should not parse HTML with regular expressions_

Comment: @Shedeki seems quite stressed already, it was my first and last point :).